# Android image cropper library java ClassCastException

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am using a popular image crop library `https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper`, everything seems correct but I am getting a run time exception i.e.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.edmodo.cropper.cropwindow.CropOverlayView cannot be cast to com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropOverlayView
```

crop_image_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageView_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    tools:ignore="contentDescription"/>

<com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropOverlayView
    android:id="@+id/CropOverlayView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/CropProgressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

The code which is having the exception:
CropImageView.java

```
private final CropOverlayView mCropOverlayView;

mCropOverlayView = (CropOverlayView) v.findViewById(R.id.CropOverlayView);
```

The exception message:

> 03-27 00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main 03-27 00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta
>   E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.fiesta, PID: 28079 03-27 00:16:12.147
>   28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.fiesta/com.fiesta.UserProfile}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error
>   inflating class com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView 03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
>   03-27 00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>   03-27 00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>   03-27 00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 03-27 00:16:12.147
>   28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 03-27 00:16:12.147
>   28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 03-27 00:16:12.147
>   28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>   03-27 00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error
>   inflating class com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView 03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633) 03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
>   03-27 00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:916)
>   03-27 00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802) 03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257)
>   03-27 00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
>   03-27 00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.fiesta.UserProfile.onCreate(UserProfile.java:62) 03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>   03-27 00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
>   03-27 00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>   03-27 00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)  03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
>   03-27 00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)  03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)  03-27 00:16:12.147
>   28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)  03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  03-27 00:16:12.147
>   28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)  03-27 00:16:12.147
>   28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>   03-27 00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)  03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 03-27 00:16:12.147
>   28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
>   03-27 00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)  03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:916) 
>   03-27 00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)  03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)  03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)  03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)  03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257) 
>   03-27 00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
>   03-27 00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.fiesta.UserProfile.onCreate(UserProfile.java:62)  03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)  03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
>   03-27 00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
>   03-27 00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>   03-27 00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)  03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
>   03-27 00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)  03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)  03-27 00:16:12.147
>   28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)  03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  03-27 00:16:12.147
>   28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)  03-27 00:16:12.147
>   28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>   03-27 00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)  03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.edmodo.cropper.cropwindow.CropOverlayView cannot be cast to
>   com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropOverlayView 03-27 00:16:12.147
>   28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView.(CropImageView.java:190)
>   03-27 00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)  03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)  03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)  03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
>   03-27 00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)  03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:916) 
>   03-27 00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)  03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)  03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)  03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)  03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257) 
>   03-27 00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
>   03-27 00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.fiesta.UserProfile.onCreate(UserProfile.java:62)  03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)  03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
>   03-27 00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
>   03-27 00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>   03-27 00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)  03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
>   03-27 00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)  03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)  03-27 00:16:12.147
>   28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)  03-27
>   00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  03-27 00:16:12.147
>   28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)  03-27 00:16:12.147
>   28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>   03-27 00:16:12.147 28079-28079/com.fiesta E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

build.grade files:

App:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.fiesta"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/search'] } }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.edmodo:cropper:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:1.2.+'
}
```

Cropper:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

ext {
    PUBLISH_GROUP_ID = 'com.theartofdev.edmodo'
    PUBLISH_ARTIFACT_ID = 'android-image-cropper'
    PUBLISH_VERSION = '1.2.3'
    // gradlew clean build generateRelease
}

android {

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName PUBLISH_VERSION
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
   }
}
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ArthurHub/release-android-library/master/android-release-aar.gradle'
```

Comment: Check your imports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the final answer to the question.

The com.edmodo:cropper:1.0.1 library is importing com.edmodo.cropper.cropwindow.CropOverlayView, I removed it and it solved the issue

the dependencies section of the build.gradle file of the application should look like this

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:1.2.+'
}
```

Comment: It didn't work and gives me an warning that the namespace is never used.

Comment: Coud you post your build.gradle file then  Add your import ?

Comment: Could you check the import as I advise in my last answer

Comment: I check it has got the package  import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper, I search for com.edmodo.cropper.cropwindow.CropOverlayView in the project, it turned out it is present in a class file which can be seen in gradle compile 'com.edmodo:cropper:1.0.1', will it cause an issue?

Comment: I think your gradle file should only contains compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:1.2.+'

Comment: OK i will edit my answer in a few minutes so it can help people who can encounter the same issue.

Comment: I have made the edit if you figure out why the other lib was causing trouble let me know. I am curious about it.

Comment: The com.edmodo:cropper:1.0.1 library was importing com.edmodo.cropper.cropwindow.CropOverlayView, I removed it and it solved the issue. I think it was probably overriding the theheartofdev import, can you edit your answer with this and i will mark it answered :)

Comment: The answer has been edited let me know if you want to add anything :)